# how to calculate correlations of two concurrent stream with multiple columns and specific window time in pyspark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have two streams of structured streaming data. i want to calculate the correlation of some column of first stream with each columns of the second stream.

I know there is Correlation in  pyspark.ml.stat library, but I couldn't find a way to use it in stream of data in specific window time-frame.

Comment: I think you'd have to `join` the streams together and perhaps `foreachBatch` to calculate correlation. What did you try?

Comment: actually ,the usage of foreachBatch is still unclear to me, how can i specify the duration of a batch in a stream which i want to join and calculate the correlation?

Comment: You can't. What did you try? It's going to be easier when we talked about a code, isn't it?